# How to read data from txt and save into array every 2 lines and remove the header

Tags: java, readfile

I want to read the data from text, then I will remove the header of the text and save the data into and array every 2 line, cause it still continues data.

visitor.txt

```
    1                   DAILY REPORT VISITOR
                            DATE : 02-02-22
    0+------------------------------------------------------------------+
        NO.     DATE            NAME                ADDRESS
        PHONE           BIRTHDAY        NEED                              
     +------------------------------------------------------------------+
          1     02-02-22        ELIZABETH ZEE       WASHINGTON DC
        +32 62          18-10-1985      BORROW BOOK
          2     02-02-22        VICTORIA GEA        BRUSEELS
        +32 64          24-05-1986      VISITOR
          3     02-02-22        GEORGE PHILIPS      BRUSEELS
        +32 76          02-05-1990      VISITOR
```

I want the data that save into an array like this.

```
1       02-02-22        ELIZABETH ZEE       WASHINGTON DC       +32 62          18-10-1985      BORROW BOOK
2       02-02-22        VICTORIA GEA        BRUSEELS            +32 64          24-05-1986      VISITOR
3       02-02-22        GEORGE PHILIPS      BRUSEELS            +32 76          02-05-1990      VISITOR
```

This is the code

```
BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myfile));
int i =0;

String line;
        
try {
    while (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    i++;
    String data = line.split("\\s", "")

    if(data.matches("[0-9]{1,3}\\s.+")) {
        String[] dataArray = data.split("\\s", -1);
        String[] result = new String[30];

        System.arraycopy(fileArray, 0, result, 0, fileArray.length);

        String data1 = line.get(i).split("\\s", "")
        String[] fileArray1 = data.split("\\s", -1);
        String[] result1 = new String[30];
 
        System.arraycopy(fileArray1, 0, result1,0,fileArray1.length);       
    }
    
}
```

The problem here is, I think this code is not effective cause it will be read the second line twice from data and data1. I want every 2 lines will save into one row in the database like the result of text. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The result has actually a dynamic number of records. Then a fixed size array
  no longer is suitable. Use [`List<String\[\]>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead: `list.add(stringArray)`, `list.get(i)`, `list.size()`, `list.isEmpty()`.
- The header seems to consist of 2 lines, but I may err.
- I saw fields with a space, hence one cannot split on `\s+` (one or more whitespace characters). I did split on `\s\s+`. Maybe you should better use the fixed length field boundaries with `line1.substring(i1, i2)`.
- FileReader uses the encoding on your current computer (=unportable file). I have made it explicit. If it always an US-ASCII file, without special characters, you could use `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`. Then you can run the software on a Linux server, that normally uses UTF-8.

So without check of data format (which however makes sense):

```
private void stackOverflow() throws IOException {
    List<String[]> data = loadData("mydata.txt");
    System.out.println(data.size() + " records read");
    for (String[] fields: data) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fields));
    }
}

private List<String[]> loadData(String myFile) throws IOException {
    List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
    Path path = Paths.get(myFile);
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader =
            Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        if (bufferedReader.readLine() != null
                && bufferedReader.readLine() != null) { // Skip both header lines.
            String line1, line2;
            while ((line1 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null
                    && (line2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] fields1 = line1.split("\\s\\s+", 4); // Split on at least 2 spaces.
                if (fields1.length != 4) {
                    throw new IOException("Wrong number of fields for first line: " + line1);
                }
                String[] fields2 = line2.split("\\s\\s+", 3); // Split on at least 2 spaces.
                if (fields1.length != 3) {
                    throw new IOException("Wrong number of fields for second line: " + line2);
                }
                String[] total = Arrays.copyOf(fields1, 7);
                System.arraycopy(fields2, 0, total, 4, fields2.length);
                ;
                data.add(total);
            }
            if (line1 != null && !line1.isBlank()) {
                throw new IOException("Trailing single line: " + line1);
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

- Substring is better, safer, than split.
- Instead of `String[]` you might use `record` class (since java 14)

  ```
  record Visitor(String no, String date, String name, String address,
          String phone, String birthday, String need) { }
  List<Visitor> data = new ArrayList<>();
  data.add(new Visitor(fields1[0], fields1[1], fields1[2], fields1[3],
      fields2[0], fields2[1], fields2[2]);
  ```

A `record` need little code, however cannot be changed, only replaced in the list.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely for me that one line would be read multiple times. Try to debug your code to see if that actually happens.

Otherwise, you could really skip the first line before starting processing:

```
BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myfile));
int i =0;

String line;
    
try {
    // alternative one
    String firstline = bufferedReader.readLine();
    String secondline = bufferedReader.readLine();
    String mergedline = firstline + secondline; // the linefeed should have been removed but the data is retained

    // alternative two
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(bufferedReader.readLine()); // first line
    sb.append(bufferedReader.readLine()); // second line
    ... = sb.toString(); // now do something with the merged lines

    // the other stuff
    while (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        // process your data lines here
    }

}
```

Comment: skip the first line is used to remove the header or what? Then, how to read the line 1 and merge into line 2 ? 
```1       02-02-22        ELIZABETH ZEE       WASHINGTON DC       +32 62          18-10-1985      BORROW BOOK
```
I want save the data like above to database, so i think it should be read line 1 then line 2 then save into new array. Then I dont know how to merge this.

Comment: Oh, so you want to preserve the data. Let me edit my response

Comment: If you have varying whitespace or other formatting in your file and still want to get good results with all the data, maybe you are better off writing a real parser.

Comment: yes i want to preserve data :D. Sorry before, in this code ```String firstline = bufferedReader.readLine(); String secondline = bufferedReader.readLine();``` the data in third line and so on will not read? Because it is not in the loop stage. I really confused with it.

Comment: readLine() will always read the next line from the file and return it. So after having it called two times the first two lines are already consumed, and then the loop starts reading eveything until end-of-file.

Comment: oh, thank you for your explanation. I am little understand. And will try it. Thanks :D